# Random matrices: stochastic dominance of trace and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, reference-request, random-matrices

For this question, if $X$ and $Y$ are 2 real random scalars, then $X$ has first-order stochastic dominance over $Y$ if for any $x$, $\Pr[X\leq x]\leq\Pr[Y\leq x]$. Let's write $X\succeq Y$.

> Suppose $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ random positive semidefinite real matrices and I'm interested in sufficient conditions that allow me to say $\operatorname{tr}(A)\succeq\operatorname{tr}(B)$ or $\det(A)\succeq\det(B)$. In particular, can I say something if I know $c'Ac\succeq c'Bc$ for all $n\times 1$ nonstochastic $c$?

Comment: In your definition, what does $y$ denote on the right-hand side of the inequality?

Comment: @JohnHughes My bad, it's typo. Should be $x$ on both sides. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For the trace, you can use $c$ equal to unit vectors to pick out the diagonal elements of the matrices.  Each diagonal element of (A) has stochastic dominance over the corresponding element of (B), the sum of r.v.s from (A) will have stochastic dominance over the sum of r.v.s from (B).

For the determinant, you can use the fact that $\det\left(M\right)=e^{\mathrm{Tr}\left(\log\left(M\right)\right)}$ (you might have to work a bit harder to deal with the case where you have zero eigenvalues).  If we take $c$ to be the various elements of an eigenvector (or Jordan) basis for $B$, then each eigenvalue of $B$ is stochastically dominated by a diagonal element of $A$ in this basis.  These elements of $A$ sum to $\mathrm{Tr}\left(A\right)$.  Since $\log$ is concave, the sum of the $\log$s of these elements should be stochastically dominated by the sum of the $\log$s of the eigenvalues of $A$.  (Please verify the details on this—I haven't checked everything very carefully and I'm leaving the details of the proof to you.)  So $\mathrm{Tr}\left(\log\left(A\right)\right)\succeq\mathrm{Tr}\left(\log\left(B\right)\right)$.  Since $e^{x}$ is an increasing function, $e^{\mathrm{Tr}\left(\log\left(A\right)\right)}\succeq e^{\mathrm{Tr}\left(\log\left(B\right)\right)}$, so $\det A\succeq\det B$.

Comment: Regarding the trace and the diagonal elements, I think you need independence when summing to preserve stochastic dominance. For example, suppose $x$ and $-x$ have the same distribution so that they each stochastically dominates $y$. But $0$ does not dominate $2y$.

Comment: @yurnero although what you are talking about is true in general, your example does not make any sense for this problem. can you see why this is true?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I get it that the $c'Ac$ and $c'Bc$ are both nonnegative so the example about $x$ and $-x$ are problematic. However, the general idea I allude to is that $x_1\succeq y_1$ and $x_2\succeq y_2$ can be both true, $x_1$ and $x_2$ can still be negatively correlated in a way that $x_1+x_2\not\succeq y_1+y_2$. More specifically, I only know of theorems that say summing preserves $\succeq$ when the summands are independent, even when nonnegativity is assumed.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Here is a silly example: $x_1\sim U(0,1)$, $x_2=1-x_1$ and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are i.i.d. $U(0,1)$. Then, $x_2$ is (marginally) also $U(0,1)$ so trivially $x_1\succeq y_1$ and $x_2\succeq y_2$ but we don't have $1=x_1+x_2\succeq y_1+y_2$.

Comment: @typographicman I have awarded you the bounty because it is expiring soon. When you have time, can you please address the issue I raised above regarding summing non-independent r.v.'s and the preservation of $\succeq$?

Comment: @yurnero what do you want him to say. His claims are wrong in general. The best he can say is: "I assumed independency". I tell you something more. It is always possible to get stochastic ordering for your problem, in case of dependency, but given a certain dependency of $x_1$ and $x_2$ one should be free to define a certain dependency between $y_1$ and $y_2$. For your last example, just take $y_2=1-y_1=1-x_1$, which seems to be unique for this case. The general case may need to be typed as another question.

Comment: @yurnero Ok, I think I got ahead of myself.  I'll have a longer, more careful look at this.